# How to get last focused field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML code :

```
<input type="button" value="1000" onclick="myFunc(this.value)" />
<input type="button" value="2000" onclick="myFunc(this.value)" />
<input type="button" value="3000" onclick="myFunc(this.value)" />
<input type="button" value="4000" onclick="myFunc(this.value)" />

<input type="textbox" value="0" name="myTextbox1" />
<input type="textbox" value="0" name="myTextbox2" />
```

and here is JS :

```
function myFunc(value){
    if($('[name=myTextbox1]').is(':focus')){
         var prevVal = $('[name=myTextbox1]').val();
         $('[name=myTextbox1]').val(parseInt(prevVal) + parseInt(value));
         $('[name=myTextbox1]').focus();
    }else if($('[name=myTextbox2]').is(':focus')){
         var prevVal = $('[name=myTextbox2]').val();
         $('[name=myTextbox2]').val(parseInt(prevVal) + parseInt(value));
         $('[name=myTextbox2]').focus();
    }
}
```

I need to add clicked buttons value to focused textbox value.
When i click button the focus is on button, so can i get last focused textbox?

Thank you ..

Comment: The _focus_ event doesn't bubble, you'll have to listen on each _Node_ you expect it to be dispatched to, keeping the most recent in a variable.

Comment: What if neither textbox has ever had focus when a button is clicked? Also, `type="textbox"` isn't valid for an `<input>` element, but (presumably) it "works" because `type="text"` is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable for lastFocused and set it in an onFocus event handler for each text box

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: can you give me an example please? @Erik

Answer (score 2):

```
var lastFocused = null;

<input type="textbox" 
    value="0" 
    name="myTextbox2"
    onfocus="lastFocused=this;"/>
```

I apologize if there are syntax errors, I'm submitting this from my phone, so I do not have a good way to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="textbox"  value="1"  class="is_focus"/>
<input type="textbox"  value="2"  class="is_focus"/>
<input type="textbox"  value="3"  class="is_focus"/>
<button class="get_data">Click</button>

$(function() {
        var focus_variable = null;

        $('body').on('focus', '.is_focus', function(e) {
            focus_variable = $(this);
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.get_data', function(e) {
            var focus_data =  focus_variable.val();
            console.log(focus_data);
        });

    });
```